# Link interactive R Markdown documents reactively

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have some interactive rmarkdown docs that I am trying to link together.  The problem is that I don't know which ones are available, so I can't hardcode the links via `[doc](path/to/doc.Rmd)`.  I can't figure out if it is possible to have a reactive list of documents from which I can create working links (so they can be clicked and the other interactive document opens).  Here are a couple failed attempts:

#### Main.Rmd

````
---
runtime: shiny
---

### This works, but not reactive
[other](other.Rmd)

```{r}
vals <- reactiveValues(rmds="other.Rmd")

ui <- renderUI({
    list(
        selectInput("doc", "Document", vals$rmds),
        actionButton("go", "Go")
    )
})

ui

## Doesn't work
observeEvent(input$go, {
    rmarkdown::run(input$doc)
})
```

```{r}
## Doesn't work
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        htmlOutput("links")
    ),
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        output$links <- renderUI({
            tags$a(href=vals$rmds, vals$rmds)
        })
    })
)
```
````

#### Other.Rmd

```
---
title: "Other"
runtime: shiny
---

## Here I am
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use a listing of the Rmd files in a path? `grep("*.Rmd", list.files("path/to/dir"), values = TRUE)` and push that?